# Multiple ItemSource for one control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox #1 below with multple textblock item templates:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2"
         x:Name="ItemListBox"                             
         ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                                       
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"                             
         AlternationCount="2"
         SelectedItem="{Binding FileSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
         BorderThickness="1">
```

I have another listbox #2 I am using to drag and drop files that is binding to an observable collection that stores the data.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DropFiles}" 
                       Grid.Row="5" Name="DropBox"
                       AllowDrop="True"                     
                       BorderThickness="1"
                       AlternationCount="2"
                       DragOver="DropBox_DragOver"
                       DragLeave="DropBox_DragLeave" 
                       Drop="DropBox_Drop" >
            </ListBox>
```

I want to implement everything on one listbox, so basically get rid of the second listbox, I can move te DragOver, DragLeave, and Drop properties to the first listbox, but I am having problem with the DropFiles ItemsSource propery of the second listbox! Any replies or suggestions appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to bind a single listbox to two collections at the same time -- one from the "Files" binding and one from the "DropFiles" binding?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!  Pretty much keep ListBox #1 as is, but move the functionality of the drag and drop from the second to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind `ItemsSource` to a single collection.

I suggest adding a property on your view model that exposes this merged collection, and use that property in your binding.

Otherwise, if `Files` and `DropFiles` are properties on the same item, you could create a converter to accept your VM class and yield a merged collection. It would be up to you to yield a collection that is observable.